# Can I combine data present in multiple files stored in different folders using powerquery?

Tags: powerquery

I want to combine data which is present in different files which are in turn stored in different folders. I've tried all I can but it seems I can only combine data from files present in a single folder. Is there any other way through which I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You may create two queries (for each folder) and then combine them:

```
= Folder.Files("C:\folder1") & Folder.Files("C:\folder2")
```